# NameError: uninitialized constant Parsers in RSpec

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm trying to test simple class in my Ruby 2.5.0 app:

`source/parsers/jira_parser.rb`

```
module Parsers
  class JiraParser
    def initialize(event)
      payload = event['body']
      @event = JSON.parse(payload)
    end

    def call
      {
        reporter_email: reporter_email,
        reporter_name: reporter_name,
        ticket_number: ticket_number,
        description: description
      }
    end

    private

    attr_reader :event

    def reporter_email
      event.dig('issue', 'fields', 'reporter', 'emailAddress')
    end
# other methods from call are pretty much the same as `reporter_email`
```

With below specs:

spec/source/parsers/jira_parser_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

RSpec.describe Parsers::JiraParser do
  describe 'call' do
    subject(:hash_creation) { described_class.new(event).call }

    let(:reporter_name) { 'john.doe' }
    let(:reporter_email) { 'john.doe@example.com' }
    let(:description) { 'This is a test description' }

    let(:event) do
      {
        'body' => {
          'issue': {
            'key': 'TEST-Board-123',
            'fields': {
              'reporter': {
                'displayName': reporter_name,
                'emailAddress': reporter_email
              },
              'description': description
            }
          }
        }
      }
    end

    it { expect(hash_creation).to be_success }
  end
end
```

But I've got an error:

> NameError:
>     uninitialized constant Parsers
>
> ./spec/source/parsers/jira_parser_spec.rb:5:in `'
>   No examples found.

Should I add something to my rspec_helper to make it works?
Right now it's pretty basic:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
    expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
  end
  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end

  config.shared_context_metadata_behavior = :apply_to_host_groups
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I understand this is just Ruby, no Rails, hence there's no magic involved. You need to make a source file available in spec file, so you have to put on the top something like:

```
require_relative '../../../source/parsers/jira_parser
```

Comment: Ok but I have to test 40 classes, is there a way to change the settings to avoid adding each classes path every time?

Answer (score 0):

Hello I am still pretty new so this might help but I believe that you need to require JiraParser

```
require 'jira_parser'
require 'jira_parser/parser'
```

This might work but the error is because you are trying to use a parser that is not accessible in your current code.

Comment: Nope, I've got an error `LoadError:
  cannot load such file -- parsers/jira_parser`

Comment: did you try just using require_relative ? Also, did you check to make sure you have jira_parser installed

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured out - all I had to do was to add `-I source` inside the `.rspec` file to will load all tested classes. So in my case `.rspec` will look like below:

`.rspec`

```
--require spec_helper
-I source
```